# Sort values by groups (several entities)

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

The problem is I want to sort by groups (e.g. 3 entities separated by a delimiter act as a group).

For certain reasons, the only separator I can use is the NULL char `'\0'`.

Take this input example (where each entity is one char for simplicity):
`'b\0s\0n\0c\0p\0f\0a\0z\0m\0'`
The result would be (by taking groups of 3 entities):
`'a\0z\0m\0b\0s\0n\0c\0p\0f\0'`, since a<b<c.

I am aware of `sort`, but unfortunately it does not work for what I am trying to do since it will sort each entities separately (no groups).

One solution would be to delimit the different groups by 2 NULL chars (e.g. `'b\0s\0n\0\0c\0p\0f\0\0a\0z\0m\0\0'`), but again `sort` is not the right tool since it does not support multi-character tab.
So, for now, I don't know any solution **in shell**.

The typical data is about a hundred groups of 3 entities: `size\0filepath\0folderpath\0` (where `folderpath/filepath` is the absolute path to the file). Since paths in Unix system can contain any character (except NULL), the only delimiter I can use is `'\0'`.

Ideally I would love a code that sort files by their size, the problem (as opposed to other SO questions I read) is here paths could have `'\n'` chars.

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: how large is the input? kB? GB? PB?

Comment: @Cyrus now edited. TL;DR `sort` does not support "grouping" and I just don't know how it would be possible to do what I want.       @jhnc a few kB, at max. I'm re-editing the question to explain more what is the data I'm working on.

Comment: it is always possible to escape so you have different unique separator characters, do normal sort, then unescape

Comment: What do you mean escape ? Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough at first, but now I wrote that the entities contains paths (where any char but NULL is allowed).

Comment: 1. choose an escape character eg. `=`.  2. replace any occurrence of `=` in the input with `==`. 3. replace any occurrence of newline with `=n`. 4. join the three elements with something (eg. `=s`) and append a newline. 5. sort. 6. split result on newline and `=s` 7. replace all `=n` by newlines and then all `==` by `=`

Comment: you can create unique single-character field separators for sort (eg. `:`) by escaping them in the original (eg. `=c`)

Comment: similarly, you could base64 encode; group; sort; ungroup; decode

Comment: Although there are potential issues with sort order if you don't choose escape sequences carefully. FWIW, solution is trivial in perl: `perl -0e 'while(!eof){push @a,<>.<>.<>} print sort @a' <input`

Comment: `sort { $a <=> $b } @a` for numeric sort

Comment: Actually, the simple solution is probably just to rearrange as: `size folderpath/filepath\0` and then you can use simple `sort -zn` since you know the first space delimits size and folder and the final slash delimits folder and file

Comment: The escaping works, did not think of that. But I find it quite complex, while using a double NULL char as a separator between groups would not require to edit as many times the sequences as with the escaping. Also, I really need `folderpath` and `filepath` separated, since I use filepath for relative path. Good idea to put the size without separator before the `folderpath` since it starts with a `/`. We still have a remaining NULL char inside a single group.

Comment: _Paths_ can have NULs but _sizes_ can't, so you can sort a sequence of `<size> <path><NUL>` strings; you only need the NUL to terminate the path, not to terminate the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `awk` and an input file containing newline characters:

```
$ od -w -An -tx1 file
 62 00 73 00 6e 0a 6e 00 63 00 70 00 66 0a 0a 66 00 61 00 7a 00 6d 0a 0a 0a 6d

$ awk -v RS="\x0" '
    NR % 3 == 1 {i = i + 1}
    { t[i] = t[i] $0 "\x0" }
    END { n = asort(t); for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf("%s", t[i]) }
' file | od -w -An -tx1
 61 00 7a 00 6d 0a 0a 0a 6d 00 62 00 73 00 6e 0a 6e 00 63 00 70 00 66 0a 0a 66 00
```

We set the record separator to NUL, populate array `t` with groups of 3 tokens, at the end we sort the array with `asort` and print. If the default sorting algorithm is not what you want see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html for explanations about the sorting options.

With GNU `sed` and `sort -z`:

```
$ sed -zn 'N;s!\x0! !;N;s!\x0!/!p' file |
  sort -z |
  sed -zn 's! !\x0!;s!/!\x0!p' |
  od -w -An -tx1
 61 00 7a 00 6d 0a 0a 0a 6d 00 62 00 73 00 6e 0a 6e 00 63 00 70 00 66 0a 0a 66 00
```

If your first token is a size we can assume that it does not contain a space. If the second is a filename we can also assume that it does not contain a slash. So, we preprocess the input to replace the first NUL in a group by a space, the second by a slash, `sort -z`, and post-process to revert the preprocessing. Adapt the `sort` options to your specific needs.

Note that in both solutions a final NUL is added. Remove it with `head -c-1` if it is an issue.

Comment: you don't need `-E` or `-n`: `sed -z 'N;N;s|\x0| |;s|\x0|/|' | sort -zn | sed -z 's| |\x0|;s|/|\x0|'`

Comment: You're right about `-E`but `-n` is not that useless: it can eliminate a trailing NUL or a final incomplete group that would otherwise pollute the sorting.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to insist on only using null delimiters, traditional Unix text tools are not generally able to cope with them portably. But many non-traditional, non-standard tools which cope fine with them are fairly ubiquitous in practice. Here are solutions in Python 3 and Perl.

```py
import sys
 
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as fh:
    seq = fh.read().split(b'\x00')
items = [b'\x00'.join(seq[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(seq)-1, 3)]
print(b'\x00'.join(sorted(items)).decode('us-ascii'))
```

Python 2 might still be the default version on some platforms where stability of the toolchain trumps convenience, security, and robustness. Python 2 had a simpler string type which was able to accommodate arbitrary binary data, so this code would probably actually be simpler in Python 2, and closer to the Perl version.

```bash
perl -0 -ne 'push @rec, $_;
  if ($#rec == 2) { push @items, join("", @rec); @rec = (); }
    END { print(join("", sort @items)) }' file
```

Both of these read all the data into memory, and thus will be inconvenient if you have more data than free RAM.

Demo: https://ideone.com/Kk7mxH